# Google maps InfoWindow closing

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm adding some info windows on my map with clicking button:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
          $("input:#ekle").click(function(){//balon ekle ve listeye ekle

            infoWindow3 = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            var en=$("input:#x").val();
            var boy=$("input:#y").val();
            var yazi=$("input:isim2").val();
            var windowLatLng3 = new google.maps.LatLng(en,boy);
            infoWindow3.setOptions({
            content: yazi,
            position: windowLatLng3,
            });

            infoWindow3.open(map);
                ekle(yazi);//adding Infowindow contecnt(value) to listbox
});
```

So I can creating InfoWindows.Now I will closing my InfoWindow with clicking an other button :

```
   function cikar(){//listeden cikarma
                    var cikarilacak=$('#liste option:selected').val();//looking listbox selected item value
                    $("#liste option[value='"+cikarilacak+"']").remove(); 
//at this step I will close my InfoWındow where I selected it's value from listbox          

}
```

I will close InfoWindow which I selected it's value from listbox.what can I do

Answer (score 0):

pass the `infoWindow`-instance as argument to the function that creates the option.

When you create the option, store the reference to the infoWindow with the option(you e.g. may use `$.data()`).

It's easy then to retrieve the reference to the infoWindow in `cikar()` and to close the infoWindow.